# When closing the sub-modal scroll-bar is not working for modal in bootstrap3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap3.2. In my web-page onclick of one button im displaying modal with some content. For this modal scroll-bar is coming if modal contains some more amount of  data.
when i'm scroll-up and scroll-down i can show the modal data clearly.
from this modal onclick of one button im displaying sub-modal with some content.

Now If i'm closing sub-modal then it showing modal with scroll-bar. Now this time, when i'm scroll-up and scroll-down it scrolls up and down the web-page data but not the modal data. scroll-bar is not working for the modal instead its scroll-up and scroll-down the  web-page data and modal is fixed with screen not able to visible its full data.

Can anyone help me for this problem.?

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap does not support "sub-modals". As stated in the documentation:

> ### [Overlapping modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
>
> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.